# How I can Install Laravel8 On mac high siera

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php, version

How I can Install Laravel8 On mac high siera.
When I create project it automatically install laravel 5 .
I have PHP 8.
How I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Please share more details, like the steps involved to start a project and your attempts to resolve the error

Comment: You should start here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation, please share any errors and details about your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project_path "^8.0"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: yes I did this, but it automatically install version 5

Comment: @NicoHaase it is just a command to create a new laravel project with the version desired